# How to remove dynamically created divs as get() success

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom

In a page I create and remove #container dynamically using append and remove.

I found an issue trying to remove a #container that was dynamically added, in the result of an ajax get().

```
function ajaxNavigation(link)
{
    $.get(''+link,function(data) {
        if(data!='KO'){
            $('#container').remove();
            $('#column_left').append('<section id="container">'+data+'</section>');
        }
    });
}
```

and later in the page

```
$('document').on("click","#button",function(){
   ajaxNavigation('link.php');
});
```

The issue is: `remove()` doesn't work, that's because #container is dynamically added.

Usually I use `on()` to  add a listener, but I don't know how to use it in the `get()` success function.

Comment: i just added details to the question, thanks!

Comment: in the moment you call remove(), is the container defined?

Comment: Are you sure data != 'KO' is ever true? Otherwise addition/removal of section container looks okay. Fiddle sample : http://jsfiddle.net/hEHUL/2/

Comment: I guess you could do a check to see if the `$('#container')` element exists first before removing it: `if(data!='KO'){ if ($('#container').length) { $('#container').remove(); }`

Comment: "The issue is: remove() dosen't work, that's becouse #cointainer is dynamically added." That's incorrect, jQuery doesn't work that way. If an element with an `id` of `container` exists when you execute that line of code, it **will** be removed.

Comment: @chridam That's totally unnecessary, jQuery already handles the case where the selector matched zero elements (the function simply doesn't act on anything).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I would have thought in this case the element is added on to the DOM dynamically an existence check would be necessary but then again I didn't know jQuery handles that already, thanks for the elightenment

Comment: @AnthonyGrist you are right, it was just an incorrect, complex, selector id. ass your reply so i can accept it